# Vue Js Base Preset in the UI but dont know where it is in code

Tags: vue.js

I am new in Vue js but I am sure this Base Preset part is not supposed to be there. I am not sure in which file it exits.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

Edit

```
/src/layouts/default/Default.vue
```

and remove this line:

```
<default-bar />
```

### Long answer

I assume that you are using [vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/) for the material UI. Further, it looks like you use the default scaffold, generated with

```
npm init vuetify
```

The layout you see is the [app layout](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/application-layout/), and the "Base Preset" is simply a placeholder text in the app bar.

Note that the scaffold uses a fairly complex architecture that can be overwhelming to beginners.

### My advice

Make sure you master vanilla vue before you start working in a project that uses vuetify, router and many other advanced features. For instance, work yourself through [the official Vue tutorial first](https://vuejs.org/tutorial/#step-1).